# Unicode Encode Error

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, unicode

When I using `pandas.to_sql` to write a df into mysql, the program gives me the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 4: ordinal not in range(256)
```

my code is just as this:

```
tony.to_sql(con=con_larry, name = 'tony', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql', chunksize=100)
```

I don't know why this error presents and how to solve it

Comment: The error tells you *exactly* what the problem is. You have to change the encoding used by your connection.

Comment: where is the string that goes into db

Comment: Study this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279  If you still have problems, come back with more details.

Comment: And [python specifics](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python).

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with whatever api you are using here so don't know which variable holds the "problematic string" but do following on the variable that holds the string to be inserted into db

```
encoded_str = your_data_string.encode('latin-1')
```

Comment: actually when I add such code tony['date'] = tony['date'].apply(lambda x: str(x).encode('latin-1')), and tony.to_sql(), still I get the above error, it is the same

Comment: date (assuming it is date object) doesn't look like is a culprit. Is there any other string which is potential from external source like scrapped data or data read from file etc.